# Unable to insert today's date in access, 12 May is taken as 5 December

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an access database with a query which inserts system date/time from Now() function to a column. My system date is 12-05-14 (12 May 14) and when it is inserting in the table is taken as 05-12-14 (5 Dec 14). Can anybody help me to get it resolved?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Please edit your question to include the VBA code you are using to construct your query.

Answer (score 0):

When you are constructing SQL, you have two options for formatting dates. One is to use the American format `mm/dd/yyyy`. The other is to use an unambiguous `yyyy-mm-dd`. I'd suggest you use Format to always coerce a date into unambiguous format, such as :

```
strSQL = strSQL & " VALUES(" & Format(Now(), "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#") & ")"
```

Comment: Thanks pteranodon for your help!

I tried your code. However what is working for me is

strSQL = strSQL & " VALUES(" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd") & ")"
Thanks again!